# Why does it appear that my random number generator isn't random in C#?

Tags: c#, random

I'm working in Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express.

I found this snippet of code:

```
    public static int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        return random.Next(min, max);
    }
```

the problem is that I've run it more than 100 times, and it's ALWAYS giving me the same answer when my min = 0 and max = 1. I get 0 every single time.  (I created a test function to run it - really - I'm getting 0 each time). I'm having a hard time believing that's a coincidence...  is there something else I can do to examine or test this?  (I did re-run the test with min = 0 and max = 10 and the first 50ish times, the result was always "5", the 2nd 50ish times, the result was always "9".

??  I need something a little more consistently random...

-Adeena

Comment: For some reason I think "consistently random" is really funny.

Comment: I'd like to add, sticking my neck out, that depending on the purpose of your application - that using pseudo-random will always (at least theoretically) make your application hackable.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The problem with min = 0 and max = 1 is that min is inclusive and max is exclusive. So the only possible value for that combination is 0.

Comment: To make matters more confusing, the documentation states that the maxValue must be greater than or equal to the minValue.  Hence, you can pass in random.Next(0,0) and it will function exactly the same as random.Next(0,1) even thought there are no numbers that match the specified input parameters.

Answer (score 32):

```
random = new Random();
```

This initiates random number generator with current time (in sec). When you call your function many times before system clock changed, the random number generator is initiated with the same value so it returns same sequence of values.

Comment: The documentation for the Random() constructor describes this issue almost verbatim: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx

Answer (score 19):

Don't create a wrapper method for Next.  It wastes cycles creating a new instance of the Random class.  Just use the same one!

```
Random myRand = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myRand.Next(0, 10).ToString());
}
```

That should give you ten random values.

As has been said--Random is pseudo-random (as all implementations are), and if you create 100 instances with the same seed, you'll get 100 instances of the same results.  Make sure that you're reusing the class.

Also, as folks have said, beware that MinValue is inclusive and MaxValue is exclusive.  For what you want, do myRand.Next(0, 2).

Comment: Doing it 10 or more times was just the test... I didn't realize that   "max" was exclusive.

Comment: Sometimes you will want a wrapper method (or more likely a wrapper class) for Random so that you can mock it.

Comment: @adeena, BlackWasp: If you need to overload/wrap Next for whatever reason, go for it.  If you're looking to just get another random value, though, use Next and use the same Random class.  That way, you're not at too much risk of getting a bunch of Random's with the same seed.

Answer (score 7):

That overload of Next() returns:

> A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not MaxValue. If minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned.

0 is the only possible value for it to return.  Perhaps you want random.NextDouble(), which will return a double between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 6):

The min is inclusive, but the max is exclusive.  [Check out the API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

You're always getting 0 because `Random.Next` returns integers.  You need to call `Random.NextDouble`, which will return a number between 0 and 1.  Also, you should reuse your Random instance, like this:

```
[ThreadStatic]
static Random random;
public static Random Random { 
    get {
        if (random == null) random = new Random();
        return random;
    }
}
public static int RandomInteger(int min, int max)
{
    return Random.Next(min, max);
}
public static double RandomDouble() //Between 0 and 1
{ 
    return Random.NextDouble();
}
```

If you want cryptographically secure random numbers, use the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class; see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163367.aspx)

EDIT: Thread safety

Comment: -1 because this code is dangerously wrong. Random is not thread-safe and you're accessing a shared instance without providing any locking or a per-thread instance.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the 0-1 issue already noted in other answers, your problem is a real one when you're looking for a 0-10 range and get identical results 50 times in a row.

`new Random()` is supposed to return a random number with a seed initialized from the timer (current second), but apparently you're calling this code 50 times a second.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(VS.71).aspx) suggests: "To improve performance, create one Random to generate many random numbers over time, instead of repeatedly creating a new Random to generate one random number.". If you create your random generator once outside the method, that should fix your "non-randomness" problem as well as improving performance.

Also consider [this post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/random07172006175425PM/random.aspx) for a better pseudo-random number generator than the system-supplied one, if you need "higher quality" pseudo-random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the Random being built multiple times per second uses the same second as the seed, so I'd put the Random constructor outside your loop, and pass it as a parameter, like this:

```
public static int RandomNumber(Random random, int min, int max)
{
    return random.Next(min, max);
}
```

Also as mentioned by others, the max is exclusive, so if you want a 0 or 1, you should use [0,2] as your [min,max], or some larger max and then do a binary AND with 1.

```
public static int RandomOneOrZero(Random random)
{
    return random.Next(0, int.MaxValue) & 1;
}
```

Comment: The Random object could also be declared as a static variable, so it doesn't need to be passed to the method every time.

Comment: I like the RandomOneOrZero method.  Are you using it because you know it to be more random than using [0,2] or for another reason?

Comment: @Matt: It'd be the same amount of randomness either time. I just whipped it up off the top of my head.

@Whatsit: Good point. I wasn't sure what her use case was, so I just guessed at it. A static or instance variable would probably be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addendum to any answers, as the answer to this specific question is the bounds should be (0, 2) not (0, 1).

However, if you want to use a static wrapper method, then you must remember that `Random` is not thread-safe, so you either need to provide your own synchronization mechanism or provide a per-thread instance. Here is a largely non-blocking implementation which uses one generator to seed each per-thread generator:

```
public static class ThreadSafeRandom
{
    private static readonly Random seed = new Random();

    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Random random;

    public static int Next(int min, int max)
    {
        if (random == null)
        {
            lock (seed)
            {
                random = new Random(seed.Next());
            }
        }

        return random.Next(min, max);
    }

    // etc. for other members
}
```

Comment: Environment.TickCount (the default seed) is good enough for a seed; there's no point in making a separate seed instance.

Comment: @SLaks - If you rely on Environment.TickCount then you'll quite possibly get the same seed for each per-thread instance, which will cause them to produce the same sequence of pseudo-random values. I very much doubt that this is what you want. By giving them an explicitly different seed, you prevent this behaviour pattern from occuring.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the line "random.Next(min, max)". "min" is in the  place of the lowest number allowed to be generated randomly. While "max" is in the place of the lowest number NOT allowed to be generated it is not in the place of the largest number allowed to be drawn. So when the line is random.Next(0, 1) you are basically only allowing 0 to be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Several posters have stated that Random() uses a seed based on the current second on the system clock and any other instance of Random created in the same second will have the same seed. This is incorrect. The seed for the parameterless constructor of Random is based on the tick count, or number of milliseconds since boot time. This value is updated on most systems approximately every 15 milliseconds but it can vary depending on hardware and system settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple, but effective way to generate random numbers by just taking the last two digits of the current datetime milliseconds:

```
   int seed = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString().Substring(1, 2));
   int cnr = new Random(seed).Next(100);
```

It is crude, but it works! :-)

Of course it would statistically generate the same number every hundred times. Alternatively, you could take all three digits or concatenate with other datetime values like seconds or so.

Answer (score 0):

Your range is not correct. The minValue is inclusive in the range and the maxValue is exclusive in the range(meaning it won't be included in the range). So that's why it returns only 0.

Another useful note: having a Random instance be created in the method is not ideal as it might get the same seed on calling. So instead i would say use:

```
static Random gen = new Random();

public static int RandomNumber(int minValue, int maxValue){
    return gen.Next(minValue, maxValue);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

in VB i always start with the Randomize() function. Just call Randomize() then run your random function. I also do the following:

```
Function RandomInt(ByVal lower As Integer, ByVal upper As Integer) As Integer
    Return CInt(Int((upper - lower + 1) * Rnd() + lower))
End Function
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: are you for real? do you know how many times i've gotten C# answers to VB questions and was able to figure out what i was doing wrong? it's the concept, man, not the syntax... jeezz...

Comment: Every single one of those functions is only available in VB (unless you reference Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll)

Comment: The System.Random class is completely different.