# Properly Seeding Random numbers in Class Library called from ASP.Net Web Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, random

I'm experiencing a problem with my random number generator in a class library returning the same value repeatedly.  It returns the same value b/c it is repeatedly initialized with the default constructor - for example:

```
public static T GetRandomValue<T>(T[] array)
{            
    int ndx = new Random().Next(array.Length);
    return array[ndx];            
}
```

This is called repeatedly from another method before the system clock can change, so it is initialized with the same random seed, giving the same value.  (see [SO article for apparently malfunctioning random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932520/why-does-it-appear-that-my-random-number-generator-isnt-random-in-c)) It is used to select a random format string for some text generation algorithms. Because it is called in rapid sequence every time my different bits of text generates with a homogeneous formatting string, which is undesirable for the application.


It is typically called from an asp.net webpage, and I'm wondering what the best approach is to produce a random sequence, without creating performance issues for the pages that call the method repeatedly.

A web page calls the library method, which calls the random number.  I am wondering if i can use this approach for a static number generator instead.  Are there performance issues associated with calling a static method like this from a webpage?

```
public class Utility
{
    public static Random random = new Random();
    public static T GetRandomValue<T>(T[] array)
    {            
        int ndx = random.Next(array.Length);
        return array[ndx];            
    }
}
```

A lock on "random" and "ndx" may be needed too.  Is there a better practice in general for handling this type of seeding in a class library?

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like the following.

```
public class Utility
{
    public static readonly Random MyRandomGenerator = new Random();

    static Utility()
    {
    }
}
```

Then just call Utility.MyRandomGenerator as if it were a regular {get;} property.

EDIT: I almost always include a static constructor when I'm doing something like this because of the nuttiness of the `beforefieldinit` flag. See this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610818/what-does-beforefieldinit-flag-do).

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is way better. The first does not guarantee a random string; you probably get arrays filled with the same value indeed. Even more so, I think the second approach is better regarding performance, because you only create one `Random` generator for the entire application.

I even think it will only be re-instantiated when the worker process recycles (can anyone verify this?).