# Problem in generating random number

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does it appear that my random number generator isn't random in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932520/why-does-it-appear-that-my-random-number-generator-isnt-random-in-c)

Dear friends

I want to generate 4 random number between 1 - 55 ,but the problem is that most of the time I receive 2 number same :( for example the generated number is 2 2 5 9 or 11 11 22 22!
I dont know why?
I use :

```
Random random = new Random();
return random.Next(min, max);
```

for generating my random number. I put them in a While for repeating 4 times. Any Idea?Would u help me plz?

Comment: Don't recreate the `random` object - reuse a single instance. See [Why does it appear that my random number generator isn't random in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932520/why-does-it-appear-that-my-random-number-generator-isnt-random-in-c)

Comment: That's the problem with randomness:  you can never be sure if it's being unusually "unrandom," or truly random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create just one Random() object and reuse it instead of creating a new one for each random number you generate.

The reason is that every time you create a new Random object it seeds itself from the current time. If you create multiple Random objects within a short period of time then then they will seed with the same time, and so they will generate the same numbers.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `new Random()` without specifying a seed, it seeds it using the current system time.

I don't remember off the top of my head the precision it uses (ticks? milliseconds?) but if you create new `Random` objects and use them in quick succession, they could easily have the same seed and thus return the same results.

Create one `new Random()`, and call `.Next(min, max)` on it repeatedly.