# Method to return two random ints always returns the same one twice

Tags: c#, random

I know how to do this in VB but im coding in C# so i need to figure out how to get two different radomized integers (1 - 8) and i cant seem to get it to work, i get the same over and over even more the harder i try. I have read up alot but i cant find a more specific help as most people just want one rnd number and that i can do...easy ;)

what i have coded is this thou it does not give me two different numbers.

```
    public string GetFruitCombination()
    {
        Random fruitcombo = new Random();
        int indexone = fruitcombo.Next(0, 8);
        Random fruitcombotwo = new Random();
        int indextwo = fruitcombotwo.Next(0, 8);

        string firstfruit = m_fruit[indexone];
        string secondfruit = m_fruit[indextwo];

        return string.Format("{0}&{1}", firstfruit, secondfruit);
    }
```

There must be an easier way to get 2 different rnd numbers right? So i need someone to push me in the right direction!

Thanks in advance for any idea and help!!!

//Regards

Comment: Use the *same* random number generator. Search for "random number duplicate C#".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887481/problem-in-generating-random-number , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-not-working-the-way-i-had-planned-c , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834589/not-so-random-number-why (for instance)

Comment: (FWIW: Java's random "default seed" implementation is better than this, but it is still possible to run into degenerate situations ..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't create a second instance of `Random`, just use the same one twice.

(The default seed is time based, so in creating two so quickly there is a significant chance they will both have the same seed.)

Comment: Thanks!! I was going crasy :P

Answer (score 2):

```
   public string GetFruitCombination() 
    { 
        Random fruitcombo = new Random(Environment.TickCount); 
        int indexone = fruitcombo.Next(0, 8); 
        int indextwo = fruitcombo.Next(0, 8); 

        string firstfruit = m_fruit[indexone]; 
        string secondfruit = m_fruit[indextwo]; 

        return string.Format("{0}&{1}", firstfruit, secondfruit); 
    }
```

Although personally I use a static version of Random so the seed is set at start up and then just Nexted each use. There is also a better random in the RNGCryptoServiceProvider example [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)