# How to use drawImage()

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem using this function to divide an image into multiple pieces and moving them a little bit.

The problem is that in the result the height of the rectangles is different from the "node_height" variable.

here is a testing image: [measure.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSwAs.jpg)
and the result: [measured.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9xu7.jpg)
in this image I used "node_height = 100". It was supposed to cut all the circles.

the code:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height);
        bmp.SetResolution(source.HorizontalResolution, source.VerticalResolution);

        int node_height = trackBar1.Value;
        int shift = trackBar2.Value;
        int image_width = bmp.Width;
        int image_height = bmp.Height;
        double division = image_height / node_height;
        int nodes = Convert.ToInt32(division);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.None;
        g.PageScale = 1;
        g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

        g.Clear(Color.Transparent);

        for(var i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
            int new_shift = RandomNumber(0,shift);

            int x = 0;
            int y = node_height * i;
            int w = image_width;
            int h = node_height;

            Rectangle source_rect = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
            Rectangle dest_rect = new Rectangle(new_shift, y, w, h);

            g.DrawImage(source, dest_rect, source_rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post an image of what it actually looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. I was getting equal numbers in random sequences. Here is a link to the solution in my case [Problem in generating random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887481/problem-in-generating-random-number)