# Why does this Random Number Generator not random?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, random

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why does it appear that my random number generator isn't random in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932520/why-does-it-appear-that-my-random-number-generator-isnt-random-in-c)
>   [Random number generator not working the way I had planned (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-not-working-the-way-i-had-planned-c)

I have this method to calculate a random value:

```
private double getMetrics(SourceFile sf)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            return (r.NextDouble());
        }
```

However it returns always the same number, in my case 0.41500350386603

Why????

Comment: Thats because you are re-initializing it every time. Move the declaration & instantiation code to some other place.

Comment: Yes but e.g. if i do that in Java nevertheless, random numbers are generated

Comment: Then the Java random class must have a different specification.

Comment: @shakalpesh: No, `new Random()` initializes it with `Environment.TickCount` as seed, so it should never display the same value (except maybe in a **very** tight loop).

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932520/why-does-it-appear-that-my-random-number-generator-isnt-random-in-c

Comment: How many times must this question still be asked? Can't we just start shooting people already for asking the same questions all the time without searching?

Comment: @shakalpesh: On second thought, he most likely used that tight loop, so I'll shut up, sorry...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`new Random()` uses the current time as the seed value. Thus, if you are calling this function multiple times in a very short time span, it might return the same value. Here's the explanation from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx):

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers. This problem can be avoided by using a single Random object to generate all random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the Random out of your method and everytime you call the method, new numbers will be created unless it gets disposed and recreated. When re-created, the numbers will be alike with the start again. You can make it wait a few ms before creating the random number if you want "more" unique numbers. If you want very unique numbers, GuID is better.