# random number generator isnt working

Tags: vb.net, random

I'm having trouble with function that generates random numbers.

I have class dice:

```
Public Class dice
    Private isHold As Boolean = False
    Private rnd As Random
    Private rolledDots As Integer

    Public Sub roll()

        If isHold = False Then
            rnd = New Random
            rolledDots = rnd.Next(1, 7)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'm rolling dices through rollcup class:

```
Public Class rollCup
    Public dices As New List(Of dice)
    Sub New()
        For i = 0 To 5
            dices.Add(New dice)
        Next
    End Sub
    Public Sub rollDices()
        For Each dice In dices
            dice.roll()
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Problem is dices arent generating random numbers. Every dice has generated same number. 
I can only achieve random numbers by sleep threading in loop:

```
Public Sub roll()
    If isHold = False Then
        rnd = New Random
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        rolledDots = rnd.Next(1, 7)
    End If
End Sub
```

or by showing each number in message box:

```
Public Sub roll()
    If isHold = False Then
        rnd = New Random
        rolledDots = rnd.Next(1, 7)
        MessageBox.Show(rolledDots)
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there any other answer to my problem ?
ps. sorry for bad english.

Comment: `MessageBox` is a terrible way to debug this kind of problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your dice class with a few changes.  Give it a try.  The problem was that you were creating a new random in close succession which caused the numbers returned to all be the same.

```
Public Class dice
    Private isHold As Boolean = False
    Private Shared rnd As New Random '<<<< note Shared
    Private rolledDots As Integer

    Public Sub roll()
        If Not Me.isHold Then
            Me.rolledDots = dice.rnd.Next(1, 7)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

See [RandomWrapper](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?780343-Random-Wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the randomgenerator is time-based, so it creates a "random" value based on the current time. And because the different dices run at practically the same time, you'll get the same random number. See: [Why isn't Random() random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818018/why-isnt-random-random)