# Random number generator always picks the same value when run inside a loop

Tags: c#, random, for-loop

The problem with the code is, when I try to generate a number, if the spin is equal 1 it generates values inside range (1,2,3) if if try to use the loop to sum random values inside the same range the random number gerated is always the same while in loop,

example, if I run the loop with:
spind3 = 4 the values go from    4, 8, 12
spind3 = 5 the values go from    5, 10, 15

That means the first time the RandomNumber generates a value inside loop, it never change until the loop completes.

```
if (toggled3.Checked)
   {
    if (spind3.Value != 1)
        {           
         for (int i = 1; i <= spind3.Value; i++)
              {
               diceCalc[1] += RandomNumber(1, 4);
              }
        }
     else
     diceCalc[1] = RandomNumber(1, 4);
     }
```

Comment: How  is implemented `RandomNumber()` method ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does it appear that my random number generator isn't random in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932520/why-does-it-appear-that-my-random-number-generator-isnt-random-in-c)

Comment: @digEmAll http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random number generator only generating one random number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are probably creating a new `Random` object inside `RandomNumber` method. The [default constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx) for `Random` uses the system time as a seed. If you create multiple `Random` objects in a tight loop the time probably won't have changed between each call so they will all be initialized with the same seed.

To fix your code you should only create one `Random` object and reuse it.

---

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx):

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different `Random` objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers. This problem can be avoided by using a single `Random` object to generate all random numbers. You can also work around it by modifying the seed value returned by the system clock and then explicitly providing this new seed value to the `Random(Int32)` constructor. For more information, see the `Random(Int32)` constructor.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are creating random generators too close in time. The random generator constructor uses the current time to seed the generator, and when you create them too close in time they will all be seeded using the same time.

Create one random generator and use in the loop:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 1; i <= spind3.Value; i++) {
  diceCalc[1] += rnd.Next(1, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your Random object, then call Next() inside your loop.

i.e.

```
if (toggled3.Checked)
{
  // initialize your total and the random number generator
  int diceTotal = 0;
  Random rand = new Random();

  for (int i = 0; i < spind3.Value; i++)
  {
    // add the next random number between 1 and 3
    diceTotal += rand.Next(1, 4); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I had declared the Randomnumber function and I was thinking it was enough ... newbie mistake. Ty all i needed was to declared Random rand = new Random();

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Random(seed)` constructor.

```
Random rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to manually create the seed by adding `DateTime.Now.Ticks` to the variable `i`:

```
Random r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks + i);
```