# F11 debugs correctly but F5 does not

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

There is a strange problem with some of my code. I've created a list of some objects; when trying to fill this list with the new objects, if I use <kbd>F5</kbd>, all the members of the list will be created exactly the same as each other!

But when I try to debug this problem by <kbd>F11</kbd>, then the members of the list will be created different from each other (which is correct). I'm using a loop to generate all members of the list, and in each iteration of the loop, I use `new` to first instantiate the object of the class and then add it to the list.

I define the list as:

1. `List<MyClass> classList = new List<MyClass>();`
2. `MyClass` contains some user defined members and methods

I could not figure out why F5 does not fill the list correctly. I tried to replicate the same problem with other classes that contain only string and integer members, but that works properly.

Comment: Are you perhaps generating the elements with a `new Random` object each time? Or using different threads?

Comment: You'll need to post the relevant code if you want anybody to have a chance of figuring this out...

Comment: Please show some more code. The loop will be of particular interest. To format the code, add a blank line before the first line of the code, and indent the fragment by four additional spaces.

Comment: It could be caused by the different speeds of F5 and F11. Since F11 steps finer, more steps and thus in general more time is required. Meanwhile something on a different thread could have influenced your list elements - a behavior you would not see if the generation happened faster (like with F5). Just a theory...

Comment: @Charmander yes I use new Random in each iteration of the loop!
Actually it is not just F11 that works properly, if I put a break point somewhere in the loop and then use F5, it works fine!

Comment: the code is:

    List<Solution> population = new List<Solution>();

                for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < 100; intIndex++)
                {
                    Solution tempSolution = new Solution();
                    tempSolution.IsEqualTo(RandomChromosome(InitSolution));
                    population.Add(tempSolution);
                }

    the method RandomChromosome(InitSolution), takes an initial solution as the input and generates a random solution.
the method IsEqualTo sets the tempSolution equal to the new randomly generated solution

Comment: thanks guys, I found the answer:   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398336/random-number-generator-always-picks-the-same-value-when-run-inside-a-loop

Comment: @abbasBozorgiRad - Please update your question instead of using comments to post code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of using **new Random()** method in each iteration of the loop. The correct way to do it is to use for example

```
rndNumber=new Random()
```

once out of the loop, and then in the loop only use the

```
rndNumber.Next();
```

More information on the solution can be find in the following link:
   [Random number generator always picks the same value when run inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398336/random-number-generator-always-picks-the-same-value-when-run-inside-a-loop)

Comment: You should post the code and/or delete the question all together if its a duplicate.