# Randomizing numbers does not work

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why does it appear that my random number generator isn't random in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932520/why-does-it-appear-that-my-random-number-generator-isnt-random-in-c)
>   [Random number generator not working the way I had planned (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-not-working-the-way-i-had-planned-c)

Hello,
I use this function (in class) to randomize numbers:

```
private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.Next(min, max);
}

public void Init()
{
    x = RandomNumber(0,500);
}
```

However if I later call multiple object to do it:

```
Obj[] obj = new Obj[64];
for( int i = 0 ; i < 64 ; i++ )
{
    obj[i] = new Obj();
}
...
for( int i = 0 ; i < 64 ; i++ )
{
    obj[i].Init();
}
```

then each object has exactly same 'x' value.

What is wrong here?

Comment: And here is a better duplicate with a thread-safe answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-not-working-the-way-i-had-planned-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Random` should only be created once and `Next` called on the single instance.

This is because by default `Random` is seeded by the current time - if called in a tight loop (like you do), the seed will be the same and the result of the pseudo-random algorithm will mostly be identical.

If you change your code to something like this, you will get better results:

```
private static Random random = new Random();
private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    return random.Next(min, max);
}
```

However, this is *not* thread safe. If you try to use this in a multi threaded application, expect problems. For a thread safe version, I suggest reading and following [this](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) article by Jon Skeet.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use a plain static variable to store a reference to an instance of `Random`, as it's not thread-safe. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx for more details.

Comment: No problem. It's a really nasty "gotcha" in .NET, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2):

The Random class is a pseudo-random number generator. It needs a unique seed value to produce unique numbers.

The default seed value is based on the current time, which will be the same because all your objects are created in a split-second.

Make the Random instance static or find a unique seed value for every instantiation to fix the problem.

Comment: See my comment on Oded's answer - using a simple static variable is a *bad* solution.