# Why do two tasks created after each other generate the same random value?

Tags: c#, random

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
    new Class1();
    })

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
    new Class2();
    })
```

In the constructor of class1 and class2 I have:

```
var timeout = new Random().Next(0, 5000);
Debug.Print(timeout.ToString());
```

The random value 'timeout' is always the same in both classes. I don't understand why..

If I add a pause between the creation of the tasks then it's not the same.

**EDIT:**

I don't understand how this is related to "[Random String Generator Returning Same String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122483/random-string-generator-returning-same-string)".

They were creating the random instance in the method. I am calling it in completely different Tasks, so they should be independent of each other.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> I don't understand how this is related to "Random String Generator Returning Same String".

It’s not directly related, although the root cause is the same. A better duplicate would be this question: [Why do I keep getting two of same random values in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7623322/1968)

It contains [an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7623343/1968) of what `new Random` does – courtesy to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx):

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers.

In other words: if you create `Random` objects in quick succession, they will produce the same random number sequence.

> He was creating the random instance in the method. I am calling it in completely different Tasks so they should be independent of each other.

It is irrelevant whether these objects are created in different threads (or `Task`s) – they only depend on the system time when they are created, on nothing else. They *are* in fact independent from each other, like you said. But they both depend on the same seed value, which is the system time at creation.

---

**The correct way of solving this** is usually to have only one instance of the `Random` class. – In fact, code such as this: `new Random().Next(…)` is code smell, since it mis-uses the `Random` class: you are not supposed to generate a new instance for every call; instead, you should reuse the same instance to generate a *sequence* of random numbers.

Unfortunately, you cannot simply use the same `Random` instance across different concurrent tasks, since the [relevant method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) is not thread safe – that is, calling it from several threads concurrently could lead to race conditions. There are several ways of getting around this, but the most fool-proof way is to use an explicit lock:

```
public Class(Random rng) {
    lock (rng) {
        var timeout = rng.Next(5000);
        Debug.Print(timeout.ToString());
    }
}
```

It’s important to note that *every* access to `rng` must be locked, otherwise this is moot.

Now you can create your tasks and run them, and get proper randomness:

```
var rng = new Random();

var tasks = new [] {
    Task.Run(() => { new Class(rng); }),
    Task.Run(() => { new Class(rng); })
};
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Note that when leaving out the `lock(…)` block, it may *seem* like you are getting correct results. This is the danger of working with concurrency and randomness: it is hard to verify whether your result is actually correct or whether it was corrupted along the way. So tread with caution.

Answer (score 11):

Parameterless `Random` class constructor uses time-related way to determine initial seed for random numbers generation algorithm.

```
public Random() 
  : this(Environment.TickCount) {
}
```

That's why when you create instances at the same time they will generate the same results.