# Issue with a Random Algorithm

Tags: c#, random

in a C# ConsoleApp, I made a method that will either return true or false, based on its possibility parameter that you give it, so if you give it 5, there's a 50% that you'll get true, same for false, give it 9, there's a 90% chance that you'll get true, 10% false.
Here it is:
(I was writing this as a tutorial, and I was explaining it in that 
balls-ThatGotNumbers-inside-a-box kinda way to make it clear, hence the name of the variable BallNumber)

```
static public bool TrueOrFalse(int possiblity)
{
      Random rand = new Random();
      int BallNumber = rand.Next(0, 10); // BallNumber values are from the interval: [0, 10[  (0, 1, 2, ....9)
      if (possiblity <= 0)
        return false;
      if (possiblity == 1)
        return (BallNumber == 0); // any number you like.
      if (possiblity == 2)
        return (BallNumber == 0 || BallNumber == 1); // any two numbers, cuz there's a 20% chance that you might get a ball from the box that has either number n OR m.
      if (possiblity == 3)
        return (BallNumber == 0 || BallNumber == 1 || BallNumber == 2); // any three numbers ... etc you got the point.
      if (possiblity == 4)
        return (BallNumber == 0 || BallNumber == 1 || BallNumber == 2 || BallNumber == 3);
      if (possiblity == 5)
        return (BallNumber == 0 || BallNumber == 1 || BallNumber == 2 || BallNumber == 3 || BallNumber == 4);
      if (possiblity == 6)
        return (BallNumber == 0 || BallNumber == 1 || BallNumber == 2 || BallNumber == 3 || BallNumber == 4 || BallNumber == 5);
      if (possiblity == 7)
        return (BallNumber == 0 || BallNumber == 1 || BallNumber == 2 || BallNumber == 3 || BallNumber == 4 || BallNumber == 5 || BallNumber == 6);
      if (possiblity == 8)
        return (BallNumber == 0 || BallNumber == 1 || BallNumber == 2 || BallNumber == 3 || BallNumber == 4 || BallNumber == 5 || BallNumber == 6 || BallNumber == 7);
      if (possiblity == 9)
        return (BallNumber == 0 || BallNumber == 1 || BallNumber == 2 || BallNumber == 3 || BallNumber == 4 || BallNumber == 5 || BallNumber == 6 || BallNumber == 7 || BallNumber == 8);

      return true; // if you give it a number higher than 10, it will return true ..
}
```

Now the method is working fine, but I wanted to prove it.
So I came up with this idea:

```
int TruePossiblity = 0, FalsePossiblity = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  bool _TRUE = TrueOrFalse(5);
  if (_TRUE) TruePossiblity  += 1;
  else FalsePossiblity  += 1;
}
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Now, what should be printed is:

```
50
50
```

The Problem, is that It either Prints:

```
100
0
```

or

```
0
100
```

So, I debugged it, and walked through it, step by step, and got amazed that it actually in the end printed:

```
50
50
```

I Immediately inserted `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);` 
right after the assignment of the variable `_TRUE`
I got better results, but not that good, the more I increase the time, the better results I get (closer results to what it should print, which is 50,50). 
when I used 200 Millisecs I actually got the required result 50,50 !

Now, There's only one thread running, which is the main thread, so there's no race goin on between threads so that things could mess up and give those unwanted results.

What is goin on ?
Could Somebody explain it ?
Can I avoid using the Sleep ?

Thank you for any tips you provide.

Comment: I believe your method can be drastically simplified. `return possiblity > 0 && (BallNumber <  possiblity || possiblity > 9);`

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Man, you made me like O_O

Comment: @ChaosPandion beat me to it :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [same random values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435947/same-random-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx) instance is seeded with the current time. Because the loop executes too fast, it uses the same time, hence you get always the same "random" value.

Instead of creating the `Random` in the method itself, you should pass it as argument or use a member variable in the class.

For example:

```
static Random rand = new Random();

static public bool TrueOrFalse(int possiblity)
{
      int BallNumber = rand.Next(0, 10); // BallNumber values are from the interval: [0, 10[  (0, 1, 2, ....9)
      // ...

      return true; // if you give it a number higher than 10, it will return true ..
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx) remarks:

> **Providing an identical seed value to different Random objects causes each instance to  produce identical sequences of random numbers**.
>
> If your application requires different random number sequences, invoke
> this constructor repeatedly with different seed values. One way to
> produce a unique seed value is to make it time-dependent. For example,
> derive the seed value from the system clock. However, the system clock
> might not have sufficient resolution to provide different invocations
> of this constructor with a different seed value. This results in
> random number generators that generate identical sequences of
> pseudo-random numbers, as illustrated by the first two Random objects
> in the following example. To prevent this, apply an algorithm to
> differentiate the seed value in each invocation, or call the
> Thread.Sleep method to ensure that you provide each constructor with a
> different seed value.

Comment: WoW, didn't know that, it worked perfect .. ThanX man for your Speed-of-Light kinda Answer .. :)

Comment: Someone gets thanked for "solving" this problem every day. :)